# Scrolling not working in div which has overflow property set to scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have javascript function which does scrolling.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function scroll() {
    $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#3').offset().top}, 2000);
    }
    </script>
```

and in html part i have one div with overflow property set to scroll.
        
    #CamListDiv{
    overflow:scroll;
    height:400px
    }

```
    <div id="CamListDiv">
    <div id="1">
    <h1>2</h1>
    <p>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</p>
    </div>
    <div id="2">
    <h1>1</h1>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
    </div>
    <h1>4</h1>
    <p>dddddddddddddddd</p>
    <h1>6</h1>
    <p>fffffffffffffffffffffff</p>
    <h1>7</h1>
    <p>dskfjdlskjflskdjflsdkjfl</p>
    <h1>8</h1>
    <p>sdfdsfsdgsgsgg</p>
    <h1>9</h1>
    <p>fhjlsdkj</p>
    <h1>10</h1>
    <div id="3">
    <h1>5</h1>
    <p>eeeeeeeeeeee</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="scroll" onclick="scroll()"/>
<
```

> On click of button i am trying to scroll screen to particular id but it is somehow not working

Comment: I've made a [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/QmuHx/) It seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to scroll your `div` instead of whole page:

```
$('input').click(function() {
    $('#CamListDiv').animate({ scrollTop: $('#3').offset().top }, 2000);
    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mrCb6/2/